# What's psycopg2 doing when I iterate a cursor?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, python-db-api

I'm trying to understand what this code is doing behind the scenes:

```
import psycopg2

c = psycopg2.connect('db=some_db user=me').cursor()
c.execute('select * from some_table')
for row in c:
    pass
```

Per [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#next) my understanding was that this was repeatedly calling `Cursor.next()` which is the equivalent of calling `Cursor.fetchone()`. However, the `psycopg2` docs [say the following](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors):

> When a database query is executed, the Psycopg cursor usually fetches
>   all the records returned by the backend, transferring them to the
>   client process.

So I'm confused -- when I run the code above, is it storing the results on the server and fetching them one by one, or is it bringing over everything at once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on how you configure `psycopg2`. See [`itersize`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.itersize) and [server side cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors).

By default it fetches all rows into client memory, then just iterates over the fetched rows with the cursor. But per the above docs, you can configure batch fetches from a server-side cursor instead.